# Make HTTP Request To Self in NodeJS / ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building an NPM module that needs to make an HTTP request to itself (the running web server). For example:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:" + (process.env.PORT || 3000) + path;
request(url, function(error, response, body){ 
  ...
});
```

Is there a way to process a request through the NodeJS pipeline without actually doing an HTTP request?

Or is there a better way to form the URL? I'm nervous that `127.0.0.1` isn't the most robust way to handle this for production sites.

Comment: Do you have the Express instance? If yes, I believe you can simply trigger the `request` event.

Comment: @gustavohenke yeah, i can require access - could you put up a simple example?

Comment: It is not possible to test requests without sending one. node's http.request or request library from mikeal are good enough to send requests. That is how you should run tests on server. Also this runs on the server itself so `127.0.0.1` should work fine.

Comment: I suggest putting the logic of that API to a Logic or Model method, then call it by passing parameters, instead of self-calling. If your intention is to get the HTML in the response, then just continue with what you're doing: normal http request

Answer (score 13):

## Self Consuming JSON API

In a self consuming JSON API, you define some functionality in some standalone controller functions and then wire the functionality up to express after the fact. Let's use a library application as an example:

## books.js

```
module.exports = {
  browse: function () {
      return Book.findAll()
  },
  read: function (options) {
      return Book.findById(options.book)
  },
  processLateFees: function () {
      // Do a bunch of things to process late fees
  }
}
```

## to-http.js

In this file we build a function that converts a controller function to an HTTP route. We take the query params and pass that to our controller as options:

```
module.exports = function toHTTP (func) {
    return function (req, res) {
         func(req.params).then(function (data) {
             res.send(data)
         })
    }
}
```

## router.js

And then we connect up our controller to our http router

```
var express = require('express')
var books = require('./books')
var toHTTP = require('./to-http')

var app = express()
app.get('/books', toHTTP(books.browse))
app.get('/books/:book', toHTTP(books.read))
app.get('/batch-jobs/process-late-fees', toHTTP(books.processLateFees))
```

So we now have an express application connected up to controller functionality. And the wonderful thing is that we can call these controller functions manually too.

```
var books = require('./books')
books.processLateFees().then(function () {
    // late fees have been processed
})
```

If you need a more in depth example of this, the Ghost blog codebase is [built](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/4265afe58044cdc3cea3c7ecd69fb756fa5e1e50/core/server/web/api/routes.js#L33) around [this pattern](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/4265afe58044cdc3cea3c7ecd69fb756fa5e1e50/core/server/api/index.js#L248). It is a very informative read.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that method inside your Model or Controller and call it inside the app if you just have one nodejs application, it needs fewer resources than to create a new request.

If you have more than one nodejs apps (or other services), it is normal to create a request to other web services with specific URL and port.

Answer (score 0):

With SolidStart, I just grabbed the `request.headers.get('Host')` which happened to be my own server. Then I made a `fetch(` request to my own server to get the SSR'd html for a page.

SolidStart also has the `APIEvent.fetch` function, which is an `internalFetch` function, which basically directly hits an api route handler, instead of appearing as an outside request.

- Solid's `internalFetch` was not working to get the SSR'd html of a page, it only works for actual api routes.

Answer (score -1):

I do it in one of my project and that works fine.
I use it in dev and prod without issues so far, because I use several nodejs applications with 3 differents web services that call themself to log in or check auhtentication. I use both express.js and sails.js (based on express.js)

Answer (score -1):

i think using request module is acceptable, it is quite fast and i use this approach when i do unit tests